# Don't we have to enter passport number when booking US domestic airline tickets?

Tags: usa, air-travel, bookings, american-airlines

I booked an airline ticket for a domestic flight in the US through www.aa.com, and it does not ask for any passport details. Is this normal? Also the site says that it take 3 hours to send ticket confirmation.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 8):

This is all very normal. A passport is not required for a domestic flight in the US, and many Americans do not have passports, but you will need one of [the forms of ID accepted by the TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) (a passport is one of them). US airlines do not collect passport information for domestic flights, [just full name, date of birth, and gender](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/security/secure-flight.jsp).

A delay while the booking is ticketed through the airline's IT systems is also typical. In my experience, they usually quote an estimate of a few hours, but it often takes just a few minutes.

Comment: Technically you don't need TSA-approved ID either if your identity can otherwise be verified, although you may be subject to extra verification without TSA-approved ID